# C include paths: Safe to use hyphen & underscore?

Tags: c, gcc, include, include-path

I realise that this may be operating-system specific, but I am trying to write cross-platform GCC code. So would like to know if it really is best to avoid these, or if am forced to choose, which would be the safer bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of header names is (C11, 6.4.7 par. 1):

```
header-name:
       < h-char-sequence >
       " q-char-sequence "
h-char-sequence:
       h-char
       h-char-sequence h-char
h-char:
          any member of the source character set except
                       the new-line character and >
q-char-sequence:
       q-char
       q-char-sequence q-char
q-char:
          any member of the source character set except
                       the new-line character and "
```

Both `-` and `_` are part of the basic source character set (5.2.1 par. 3). But the standard leaves much stuff related to `#include` implementation-defined.

In practice I don't see any problems in using them. I'm not aware of a file system that disallows or assigns a special meaning to them. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) doesn't list one either.